# Debug Assertion Failed fileread

Tags: c, data-structures, filereader

```
FILE * f;
f = fopen("Depozite.txt", "r");

char* token, file_buf[LINESIZE], sep_list[] = ",";
while (fgets(file_buf, sizeof(file_buf), f)) {
    token = strtok(file_buf, sep_list);
    tmpDepozit.idDepozit = (char*)malloc((strlen(token) + 1) * sizeof(char));
    strcpy(tmpDepozit.idDepozit, token);

    token = strtok(NULL, sep_list);
    tmpDepozit.capacitate = atoi(token);

    token = strtok(NULL, sep_list);
    tmpDepozit.nrTipuriCereale = atoi(token);

    tmpDepozit.listaCereale = (char**)malloc(tmpDepozit.nrTipuriCereale * sizeof(char*));

    for (int i = 0; i<tmpDepozit.nrTipuriCereale; i++) {
        token = strtok(NULL, sep_list);
        tmpDepozit.listaCereale[i] = (char*)malloc((strlen(token) + 1) * sizeof(char));
        strcpy(tmpDepozit.listaCereale[i], token);
    }

    token = strtok(NULL, sep_list);
    tmpDepozit.procentIncarcare = (float)atof(token);

    inserareHTable(HTable, tmpDepozit, DIM);
}
```

Debug Assertion Failed!

```
             Program:

             C:\Users\Matthew\Documents\project\homework\debug\

             File: minkernel \crts \ ucrt \ src \ appcrt \stdio\ fgets.cpp

             Line: 33

             Expression: stream.valid()

             Abort   Retry  Ignore
```

That windows pops in every time i try to run my program in Visual Studio 2017. I would like to read a txt file in but this is always mess up my program. Any idea how to prevent it? (my txt file is in the same file with the source.c)

Comment: `file_buf` is a `char *` array but should be a `char` array.

Comment: when calling `strtok()`, always check (!=NULL) the returned value before using that value; to assure the operation was successful

Comment: To help us determine the problem(s) with your code, when asking a question about a run time problem, as this question is doing, please post a [mcve]  Which, in this case, should also include a couple sample line from the input file

Comment: which line is #33?